# Kivy, PyInstaller - packaging executables for Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy, pyinstaller

I've been using Kivy and PyInstaller for a while. 
However, I'm still trying to get satisfactory results on Raspberry Pi.
Right now, I'm unable to successfully run any programs where I packed any additional files into the executable (I'm successfully doing it on Linux and Windows, packaging programs as a single EXE with all the libraries and data files included. No such luck on Raspberry Pi).

I've recently updated to a new system on my Raspberry Pi and run some tests.

**System:** KivyPie 0.9b, with Kivy v1.9.2, Python 3.4 and PyInstaller-3.2.

I'm using 3 programs for testing:

- A standard Kivy example "bezier.py"
- My own program, using Kivy, that needs some data files (such as images) packaged with it.
- A simple python "Hello world", without using Kivy

The results of running the programs compiled with PyInstaller with different options:

1. "Bezier" example, default PyInstaller compilation, no flags, no changes in spec file:

> Runs successfully

2. "Hello world" without Kivy, compiled with "--onefile", as a single executable:

> Runs successfully

3. My program, spec file edited to collect data files into the program folder. All libraries in the same folder:

> Runs successfully

4. My program, spec file edited to pack data files into the executable. All libraries are still in the same folder:

> Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIkn0Qf3/libpython3.4m.so.1.0':
>   /tmp/_MEIkn0Qf3/libpython3.4m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory

5. "Bezier" example, compiled with "--onefile" (all libraries packed into the executable):

> Failed to write all bytes for
>   kivy.lib.vidcore_lite.egl.cpython-34m-arm-linux-gnueablfh.so

6. Same as Test #4, when run AFTER trying test #5, somehow gives a different error:

> Failed to write all bytes for [relative/path/to/image.png]

For some reason it no longer complains about the library, but about the packaged data - in this case, image.

I haven't been able to find much info about these issues online.
Are there any specific guidelines regarding packaging files with PyInstaller into the executable, specific to Raspberry Pi, while using Kivy?
My main goal is to package the data files - packaging libraries is secondary.

I think it may have something to do with specifying file/library paths. Actually, for my data files, my program uses a function to generate absolute path.
As far as I remember, it was pretty much required when packaging these files into the EXE on Windows.
Or perhaps something should be done with PyInstaller's spec file?

Comment: `libpython3.4m.so.1.0` why is there `.1.0`? I don't think it should be there. Don't have a clue about `5.`, but with `6.` you need to append mei paths to kivy paths. Only relative ones won't go. Read [this] answer, it's perfect. You may try `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` too.

Comment: I don't think ".1.0" is part of the problem, having numbers after ".so" extension is quite common in Linux.

As for the file paths, that's what I do - all calls to files in my program first use a function that generates an absolute path. (but yes, the error message still shows the relative path...)

Comment: I don't mind it, I just wanted to say that maybe it _expects_ a file without 1.0. Try to rename to classic `.so`.

Comment: @kaptan By now I don't even remember if I managed to pack the files into the executable, because later I just started packing them into a separate data file - which was more efficient for my program anyway, as I needed several data files that were interchangeable, and this way I didn't need to compile a separate executable for every program variant.